# In MarkLogic 9 how to update a column in a template that is already created

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I have created a template with some x columns. Let us say I want to add one more column, how I can update the template ?

Looking into MarkLogic doc there is tde functions only for Insert.

Comment: Please, explain what you mean by 'template with some x column'.

Answer (score 3):

The TDE API is based on whole templates. There's no command to "add this column to this template." Rather, insert the updated whole template and it will overwrite the original.